# Problems with mysqli query in pagination

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

This is what my connection.php says:

```
<?php
$server='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';
$db='login-rmnews';

$con=new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$db);
?>
```

That is just an additional info. The problem is with my pagination script. Is there anything wrong with the following query?

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT (id) FROM paragraph WHERE approved='1'";
```

Because when I use it I get this:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

It won't happen if I use the following query:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM paragraph ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Similarly, this query gives an error:

```
$sql="SELECT id, paragraph_heading, page_name, paragraph_contents FROM paragraph WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
```

But this doesn't:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM paragraph ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Now the problem is that I need to limit the rows in my pagination and that is not possible with the query given above.

---

Additional details:

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$limit='LIMIT' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
```

---

**Can anybody please help? I really need to overcome this issue for my project**

Comment: Try this: SELECT COUNT (id) as id ...

Comment: $limit = 10;
$sql="SELECT id, paragraph_heading, page_name, paragraph_contents FROM paragraph WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY id DESC limit $limit";

Comment: As a side note, if you are not restricted to using other technologies in your project, you should check some nice and very easy to use datatables out, which handle a lot of pagination, searching and many more.  http://datatables.net/

Comment: Well I could have use LIMIT 10 too but that way it only limits it and doesn't shift it to the other page.

Comment: And I don't know any other pagination methods I am a beginner and learnt this method from a video. His worked fine, mine show error. Don't know why

Comment: And I've also figured out that if I don't use WHERE approved='1' then it works fine and also it worked fine with $limit=10 but the problem remains the same. **It doesn't shift to the next page and all pages show the same 10 rows**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have figured out the problem and answering my own question to help others if they had the same issue.

All you need to do is change this code from:

```
$limit='LIMIT' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
```

To:

```
$limit='' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
```

and this one:

```
$sql="SELECT id, paragraph_heading, page_name, paragraph_contents FROM paragraph WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
```

To:

```
$sql="SELECT id, paragraph_heading, page_name, paragraph_contents FROM paragraph ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit";
```